# Group specific points to categories in Highchart

Tags: highcharts, categories, series

http://jsfiddle.net/e4ejk/

How can I get the first data-values into the first categories and the 3rd and 4th point into the 2nd category and so on??

```
 xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb']
        },

        series: [{
            data: [                   
                {name: 'Jan',  y:25}, {name: 'Jan',  y:23}, {name: 'Feb',  y:2}, {name: 'Feb',  y:5}
                    ]        
        }]
```

Comment: Could you explain how it should look like? In case when you use categories, in data, you need to index of category like: 0, 1 etc, not string ('jan') etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure what you are trying to achieve; however, it looks like your data should to be in two (or more) separate series.

```
series: [{
    data: [25, 2]
},{
    data: [23, 5]
}]
```

I have [updated your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e4ejk/1/)...

---

Here is an [example from Highcharts](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/chart/reflow-true/) on how to use categorizes.